# Getting client hostname in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

is it possible to get *hostname* in Node.js?

**This is how I get client's IP:**

```
var ip = request.header('x-forwarded-for');
```

**So, how do I get client's hostname?**

```
var hostname = request.header('???');
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: What makes you think they have one? :)

Comment: So not everybody has hostname?

Comment: definitely not, that's a reverse DNS lookup, and everyone may or may not have one.

Comment: Actually, even if HTTPD have this ability, it would be disabled in realworld installations. Because its slow. BTW, X-FORWARDED-FOR is proxy header, correct one is REMOTE_ADDR. (and REMOTE_HOST in case of hostname lookups)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the only way you can do it is like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/gethostname">
    <label for="hostname">What is your hostname?</label>
    <input type="text" name="hostname" id="hostname">
</form>
```

But I would suggest you don't really need it, it's not like you can do anything useful with the information.  If you just want a string to identify with the user's machine then you can make something up.

If what you're really after is the FQDN then I would suggest it's still not really that useful to you, but for that you need [Reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).  If you're on a VPS or similar you can probably configure your box to do this for you, but note that it'll likely take a few seconds so it's not a good idea to do it as part of a response.  Also note, you'll not be getting the user's machine's FQDN in most cases but that of their router.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the 'dns' module to do a reverse dns lookup:

```
require('dns').reverse('12.12.12.12', function(err, domains) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
        return;
    }
    console.log(domains);
});
```

See: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/all.html#dns.reverse

Answer (score 14):

I think this might help you. That's not exactly the client hostname but the ip address.

```
function getClientAddress(req) {
  return req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
}
```

Comment: not true, it uses the remote address if the connection wasn't proxied

Comment: You should make that clearer in your post, but +1 all the same

Comment: Solves the issue for local development and having the app on Heroku behind a reverse proxy! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same if you're using socket.io in the following manner:

```
// Setup an example server
var server = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

// On established connection
server.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // Get server host
    var host = socket.handshake.headers.host;

    // Remove port number together with colon
    host = host.replace(/:.*$/,"");

    // To test it, output to console
    console.log(host);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using express,

then you can do as follows,

```
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express.createServer();
app.listen(8080);

app.get("/", function (req, res){
    console.log("REQ:: "+req.headers.host);
    res.end(req.headers.host);
});
```

Comment: As explained before, if the request has been proxied, the host header don't have the correct data.

Comment: When I try this, `req.headers.host` contains the host name of the *server* right down to the "8080" port being used.

Answer (score -1):

You can get hostname from the os module:

```
var os = require("os"); 
os.hostname();
```

Comment: This gives server's hostname.