# Get client hostname in Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hostname

Is it possible to get client's hostname in Node / Express?

Something similiar to `req.connection.remoteAddress` which is used to obtain client's IP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255264/getting-client-hostname-in-node-js

Pls check this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a example:

```
var http = require('http'),
    dns  = require('dns');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  dns.reverse(ip, function(err, hostnames) {
    res.write("Ip: " + ip + "<br />");
    res.end("Your hostname(s) are " + hostnames.join("; "));
  });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Read more on the official Node.js documentation website:
 http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.18/api/dns.html#dns_dns_reverse_ip_callback

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried searching the [Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html)?