# req.headers.host in Express.js returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, express

I am trying to get the host accessing my site in Express.js, I am using the following code

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.headers.host)
});
```

Although this code returns `127.0.0.1:1000` which is the correct port, but it's not the external address accessing it, any reason why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Could be that wherever your server is, its behind a network device that is not passing through all of the request headers. Console the entire req.headers object and see what is being passed through.

Answer (score 1):

Not every client has a host name, as indicated in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255264/getting-client-hostname-in-node-js) you can try to obtain the client IP address with the following code, though:

req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress

Comment: I want to get the URL requested on the site, as I need to get the subdomain.domain.com, not the client IP

Answer (score 0):

Either you've pointed your browser directly to `http://127.0.0.1:1000` or you're using a local reverse proxy. In the second case your proxy must be configured to set a proper Host header.