# Nodejs express request headers - get the referrer, etc.

Tags: node.js, express

I get a post form a payment gateway https to verify a payment etc. I need to verify that the post was infact from the domain.

Im trying to verify that the referrer is from a certain list of domains but in my req.headers I dont see a referrer|referer options:

```
{ 'x-real-ip': '123.34.45.176',
  'x-forwarded-for': '123.34.45.176',
  host: 'my.foo.com',
  'x-nginx-proxy': 'true',
  connection: 'close',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-length': '441',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```

Why is my headers empty of those fields such as referer, origin etc ?

This is inside a post:

```
app.post('/payment/notify/', function(req, res){
   req.headers
})
```

Comment: Perhaps I could check if the IP address is one of the domain names?

Comment: Yup this is what I will do, get the hostname form the IP address. I dont think they send me the origin because of HTTPS. Im using dns module to get the hostname. like in this answer by prestaul http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255264/getting-client-hostname-in-node-js

Answer (score 13):

Not all requests have a referer header.

If the last page a browser was on is a secure server (https) then it does not transmit a referer to you.

Also, if your user types your address into their address bar you don't get a referer as well.

Comment: In my case I get a post from a payment gateway to confirm a payment. I need to verify that its coming from the payment domain. What do you propose?

Comment: Relying on the referer is not a secure way of determining if a payment has been made.  You need to setup some sort of backend query to the payment gateway.  As an example, when one does facebook login in an app, the app gets an access token from facebook which it then passes to the server and the server makes a request to facebook to verify the access token.  You don't just take the app's word for it.  That's not secure.  So if you need to know if a payment was made, you need to make a backend request to the payment gateway.

Comment: Header information can be spoofed, especially `Referer`, therefore relying on it is BAD

Comment: so what is the right way to know where request originated from ?
the request might have come from some server using some backend not browser 
is host property right thing to check ?