# How to get client computer name in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can any one help me  in getting clients machine-name/host-name for my website authentication.which is running internally in my company domain.
I tried the below code but got server host-name instead of client.

```
var os = require("os");
var hostaddress = os.hostname();
```

I know a way to get ip address of client using below code

```
req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Since ip address will change in change of internet connection.I want to autenticate with computer name.Please help me in getting computer name of client login to my site.

Comment: did you get the client computer name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS DNS Reverse Lookup will do the trick. It is the only way. Check this link for more information :)

https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_reverse_ip_callback

Try this below code

```
require('dns').reverse(req.connection.remoteAddress, function(err, domains) {
    console.log(domains);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.This is helpful.Thank you again.

Comment: @Yalamanchili why did you reject my edit on your answer ? Did you at least test your code, it's not working because of the `'` after `remoteAddress` or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

To get ip Address of the client system or of any system you can do this.

Change req to whatever nomenclatural you are using

```
var ip = (req.headers["X-Forwarded-For"] || req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || '').split(',')[0] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
console.log("ip address is:- " + ip);
```

To get the host name of the client system or of any system you can do this

```
const os = require('os');
var hostname = os.hostname(); 
console.log("Hostname is:- " + hostname);
```

This will work on both js and nodejs

Comment: os.hostname you will not be getting the hostname of the client, but the server hostname.

Answer (score 0):

So, how do I get client's hostname?

```
  request.headers.host
```

hope this also works for you.

Comment: No..getting "Undefined" as output

Comment: can you visit this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255264/getting-client-hostname-in-node-js , hope this solve your issue

Comment: fyi: this is a user reported value, letting the server know, where to route the request. It is not related to the client and little to the server hostname.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getClientAddress(req) {
  return req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
}
```

This will work !!

Comment: Hi,I need to get client hostname.not ipaddress :(

Comment: if you are using express,
then you can do as follows,

`var express = require("express"); 
var app = express.createServer();
app.listen(8080);

app.get("/", function (req, res){
    console.log("REQ:: "+req.headers.host);
    res.end(req.headers.host);
});`

Comment: @harikrishna got your answer ?